# Save and Save As fails in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

When "Save" or "Save As", I get a following error in MS Word 2019 (and now also in 2016) - in a yellow bar - translated to English

> Automatic save failed. We fail to save your newest changes. If you
> want to keep them, please save the file under different name. [Save
> As]

But, no matter what file name or path I choose, my changes cannot be saved!!! What is this, how to fix this? No problem of saving different Word files in the same directory. This file I am modifying was sent to me and I saved it from mail. Where can be the problem? Can there be some special permissions? But in that case MS Word should warn me, right?

PS: I also don't get why it says **Automatic** save failed. The save was **not** automatic, I tried to save it manually!

**EDIT:** found a similar thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/autosave-failed-we-have-not-been-able-to-save-your/1c54ddf4-8707-496b-ba3e-96837d461b76

**EDIT:** I do not remember how I solved the problem in January, but now I ran into the same issue again. I copy pasted the document to new one and save failed again. But I found out that accepting all revisions removes the problem. By halving the problem sequentially, I found that the revision which was making the problem was an added text with inline formula. I accepted that part of the revision and the document got saved without problems.

**EDIT:** Now the same problem, in the Word from Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 (Windows 10). And the same solution - accepted the revisions with inline formulas and saving works fine now!

[image]

Comment: Select all content and copy-paste into a new file.

Comment: Is this machine connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Comment: @Tomas  - Since this question as been modified it's on the front page.  You should provide an English translation to the message in the screenshot.  Please also indicate if you are logged into a Microsoft Account within Office.  Additonally, indicate the path you are using, to save the file.

Comment: @Ramhound the translation is already provided and the path is answered as well - it didn't matter what path I chose. Path wasn't the problem, the state of the document was. It's a bug. I don't have Microsoft Account.

Comment: Automatic save in my experience requires saving to OneDrive when using Office 2016+, if you confirmed it to be a bug, you should submit an answer

Comment: @Ramhound. The save was not Automatic, it was manually done by me, see the first sentence of the Question. Only the error reports so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: accept revisions with inline formulas.**

I copy pasted the document to new one and save failed again. I found out that accepting all revisions removes the problem. By halving the problem sequentially, I found that the revision which was making the problem was an added text with inline formula. I accepted that part of the revision and the document got saved without problems.

Answer (score 0):

> When "Save" or "Save As", I get a following error in MS Word 2019 - in
> a yellow bar -

**(A)** Make sure you have permission to the folder where you are trying to save. Generally you cannot save in someone else's user; Program Files folder; Windows; or other secured folder.

**(B)** If not (A), try an Office Repair (Control Panel, Programs and Features, click on Office, Change, Repair).

**(C)** If not (B), uninstall Office, restart the computer and install Office again and test.

This does assume the Word file is good - most are.

**(D) Other steps and thoughts.**

Once files are closed, you can repair a Word document (if not lost) by selecting Open and Repair when you open the document.

You may be able to copy text and paste it into a new document you can save. Do that and make sure you have a copy of most of or all of what you need.

Finally, Word (and Excel) have Auto Recover functions (Word Options).  You can look there if you have to close Word.

Comment: definitely not (A)... but with (B), I will have to exit Word and lose changes?

Comment: You think it's broken office installation, not the file?

Comment: I will have to exit Word and lose changes?   ...   You have to perhaps try saving to a USB key. Otherwise you may lose changes because something has gone wrong.

Comment: You think it's broken office installation, not the file?    ..  It could be either and not really  possible to say.

Comment: I cannot save this file to ANY location! Its crazy. Thanks!

Comment: It appears it could be a damaged document (I added that to my post).  Review all my steps once you have closed the document. If it cannot be saved, then you may lose changes. Word has an Auto Recover function. Try that (added to post).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my solution was to remove all non-text objects from my document and try again.

In my case, all images were corrupted.

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).